# How to improve Javafx 3d performance?

Tags: java, javafx

I am doing a javafx visualisation application for 3d points. As I am new to javafx, I started from the tutorial provided in the oracle website:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/graphics-tutorial/javafx-3d-graphics.htm#JFXGR256

The example above runs perfect on my Mac, But after adding more points, the mouse drag, which causes the camera to rotate and thus people can view the objects from different angle, became very slow and simply not applicable any more.

I currently have a data for a rabbit with about 40000 points:
[image: visualisation of a rabbit with about 40000 points]

The code I used to rotate camera:

```
cameraXform.ry.setAngle(cameraXform.ry.getAngle() - mouseDeltaX * MOUSE_SPEED * modifier * ROTATION_SPEED);            
cameraXform.rx.setAngle(cameraXform.rx.getAngle() + mouseDeltaY * MOUSE_SPEED * modifier * ROTATION_SPEED);
```

which is the same as in the oracle example.

What I have tried:

1. set JVM flag -Djavafx.animation.fullspeed=true, this helped a bit, but not significant.
2. set JVM flag -Djavafx.autoproxy.disable=true, this did not help.
3. set Cache to true and CacheHint to Cache.SPEED, this did not make much difference.
4. create another thread to do the rotation, and sync back after calculation, this did not help neither.

Any help is appreciated.Thanks in advance!

Comment: You did not provide so much information about your actual application. My gut feeling is that any slowdown is not related to the camera transform, but to the structure of the remaining scene graph. Or to put it that way: **If** you are rendering these 40000 points as 40000 spheres, then it's not a surprise that it becomes too slow...

Comment: @Marco13 Thanks for your reply. Yes, I am rendering points as spheres, because I need to set a mouse moved event for every point so I can show its coordinates if you put your mouse on it. Can you give me any advice so that I can put these 3d points in one node (if it is possible) and I can display its coordinates (x, y, z) once I move the mouse on it? Thanks!

Comment: For the 3D part of JavaFX, they obviously borrowed some concepts from Java3D, and there, we had the same problem. I don't know a "nice" solution for that. One could manage the whole geometry manually (in a `TriangleMesh`) and do the picking manually, but this would imply a *considerable* effort, and this is hardly feasible here. A first, simpler attempt could be to replace the `Sphere`s with `Box`es: They are *much* less geometry, thus probably faster, you will hardly notice a visual difference at a zoom level like that in the screenshot, and they still allow mouse-hovering - just an idea...

Comment: I followed the same guide and I also have the issue that my 3D model is slow. My model is actually really simple: it uses only instances of `Box` of different sizes, yet after adding more than 20k instances to a scene, rotating, zooming and translating becomes slow up to the point it is not user friendly. I have depth buffer enabled on the scene that is rendering. Did you manage to find a solution?

Comment: @Warkst hi, I finally switched to opengl and it runs so much faster.

Comment: @PanLong okay, thanks! Is it easy to embed in a javafx application?

Comment: There are a few Java wrappers of opengl. I forgot which one I went with. I'm not sure what your application is doing, but if you have abstracted away the rendering, if should be fine.

Answer (score 3):

Here is how I made a point cloud using tetrahedrons in a triangle mesh.  seems to run faster than using spheres or squares.  this code helped me [scalafx google code](https://code.google.com/p/scalafx/source/browse/scalafx-demos/src/main/scala/scalafx/graphics3d/TriangleMeshDemo.scala?spec=svn5e0be60b6e58ef2ec6ec254031f9136dd1717c4d&r=5e0be60b6e58ef2ec6ec254031f9136dd1717c4d)

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javafx.scene.shape.TriangleMesh;

public class TetrahedronMesh extends TriangleMesh {
    private ArrayList<Point3i> vertices;
    private int[] facesLink;

    public TetrahedronMesh(double length, ArrayList<Point3i> v) {
        this.vertices = v;
        if (length > 0.0) {
            float[] points = new float[vertices.size() * 12];
            int[] faces = new int[vertices.size() * 24];
            facesLink = new int[vertices.size() * 4];
            float[] texCoords = new float[vertices.size() * 12];
            int vertexCounter = 0;
            int primitiveCounter = 0;
            int pointCounter = 0;
            int facesCounter = 0;
            int texCounter = 0;
            for (Point3i vertex : vertices) {
                vertex.scale(100);
                points[primitiveCounter] = vertex.x;
                points[primitiveCounter + 1] = (float) (vertex.y - (length
                        * Math.sqrt(3.0) / 3.0));
                points[primitiveCounter + 2] = -vertex.z;
                points[primitiveCounter + 3] = (float) (vertex.x + (length / 2.0));
                points[primitiveCounter + 4] = (float) (vertex.y + (length
                        * Math.sqrt(3.0) / 6.0));
                points[primitiveCounter + 5] = -vertex.z;
                points[primitiveCounter + 6] = (float) (vertex.x - (length / 2.0));
                points[primitiveCounter + 7] = (float) (vertex.y + (length
                        * Math.sqrt(3.0) / 6.0));
                points[primitiveCounter + 8] = -vertex.z;
                points[primitiveCounter + 9] = vertex.x;
                points[primitiveCounter + 10] = vertex.y;
                points[primitiveCounter + 11] = (float) -(vertex.z - (length * Math
                        .sqrt(2.0 / 3.0)));
                faces[facesCounter] = pointCounter + 0;
                faces[facesCounter + 1] = pointCounter + 0;
                faces[facesCounter + 2] = pointCounter + 1;
                faces[facesCounter + 3] = pointCounter + 1;
                faces[facesCounter + 4] = pointCounter + 2;
                faces[facesCounter + 5] = pointCounter + 2;
                faces[facesCounter + 6] = pointCounter + 1;
                faces[facesCounter + 7] = pointCounter + 1;
                faces[facesCounter + 8] = pointCounter + 0;
                faces[facesCounter + 9] = pointCounter + 0;
                faces[facesCounter + 10] = pointCounter + 3;
                faces[facesCounter + 11] = pointCounter + 3;
                faces[facesCounter + 12] = pointCounter + 2;
                faces[facesCounter + 13] = pointCounter + 2;
                faces[facesCounter + 14] = pointCounter + 1;
                faces[facesCounter + 15] = pointCounter + 1;
                faces[facesCounter + 16] = pointCounter + 3;
                faces[facesCounter + 17] = pointCounter + 4;
                faces[facesCounter + 18] = pointCounter + 0;
                faces[facesCounter + 19] = pointCounter + 0;
                faces[facesCounter + 20] = pointCounter + 2;
                faces[facesCounter + 21] = pointCounter + 2;
                faces[facesCounter + 22] = pointCounter + 3;
                faces[facesCounter + 23] = pointCounter + 5;
                facesLink[pointCounter] = vertexCounter;
                facesLink[pointCounter + 1] = vertexCounter;
                facesLink[pointCounter + 2] = vertexCounter;
                facesLink[pointCounter + 3] = vertexCounter;
                texCoords[texCounter] = 0.5f;
                texCoords[texCounter + 1] = 1.0f;
                texCoords[texCounter + 2] = 0.75f;
                texCoords[texCounter + 3] = (float) (1.0 - Math.sqrt(3.0) / 4.0);
                texCoords[texCounter + 4] = 0.25f;
                texCoords[texCounter + 5] = (float) (1.0 - Math.sqrt(3.0) / 4.0);
                texCoords[texCounter + 6] = 1.0f;
                texCoords[texCounter + 7] = 1.0f;
                texCoords[texCounter + 8] = 0.5f;
                texCoords[texCounter + 9] = (float) (1.0 - Math.sqrt(3.0) / 2.0);
                texCoords[texCounter + 10] = 0.0f;
                texCoords[texCounter + 11] = 1.0f;
                vertexCounter++;
                primitiveCounter += 12;
                pointCounter += 4;
                facesCounter += 24;
                texCounter += 12;
            }
            getPoints().setAll(points);
            getFaces().setAll(faces);
            getTexCoords().setAll(texCoords);
            // getFaceSmoothingGroups().setAll(0, 1, 2, 3);
        }
    }

    public Point3i getPointFromFace(int faceId) {
        return vertices.get(facesLink[faceId]);
    }
}
```

`Point3i` code as follows

```
public class Point3i {
    public int x;
    public int y;
    public int z;

    public Point3i() {
        x = 0;
        y = 0;
        z = 0;
    }
}
```

Picking the point using the scene

```
scene.setOnMousePressed(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent me) {
            PickResult pr = me.getPickResult();
            int faceId = pr.getIntersectedFace();
            if (faceId != -1) {
                Point3i p = tetrahedronMesh.getPointFromFace(faceId);
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: That's similar to what I suggested in the comment. The difficulty will here probably be that the asker also needed some "mouse-over"/picking functionality. Should be worth +1 nevertheless...

Comment: the getPointFromFace function returns the point based on selected triangle

Comment: Oh, I see, `PickResult` provides the intersected face (I'm not so familiar with JavaFX (yet), sorry...)

Answer (score 1):

Something that helps a lot is to set the mouse transparent on the root with:

```
root3D.setMouseTransparent(true);
```

This obviously disables clicking or hovering on objects of the view (i.e PickResult is null). The solution for that is to temporarily enable it when there is a click for example and simulate another identical click with impl_processMouseEvent.

```
@Override
    public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
        try {
            if (event.getEventType() == MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED
                    && event.isStillSincePress()
                    && (event.getTarget() == scene3d || event.getTarget() instanceof Shape3D)) {

                Parent root3D = scene3d.getRoot();

                // if the 3D scene has been set to mouse transparent,
                // then we send another event and we disable the transparency temporarily
                if (root3D.isMouseTransparent()) {
                    root3D.setMouseTransparent(false);
                    try {
                        scene3d.impl_processMouseEvent(event);
                    }
                    finally {
                        root3D.setMouseTransparent(true);
                    }
                }
                else {
                    // here you get the pick result you need :)
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, But for others ..

Instead of creating a new shape all together, each of the predefined shapes
Sphere, Box, Cylinder, allow you to set the number of divisions in the constructor.

Sphere for example defaults to 64 divisions, 32 for longitude, 32 for latitude.
you can easily do  ... = new Sphere(radius, divisions); (4 is the minimum I believe for Sphere).

Comment: i tried thisbut it still rotates as if the object is stuck in syrup.